# What is the difference between a x.func() and func(x)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What would be the difference between `x.func()`
and `func(x)`?
Thanks!

Comment: one calls a method on the instance x, and the other calls a function with argument x

Comment: I remember having answered this question in detail before :)

Comment: :D:D:D:D:D:D:D:D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@flakes answered your question, but if you want to see what it looks like implementation-wise it is something like this:

```
def func(x):
    print("func(x) calls function func passing x as a parameter.")

class X:
    def func(self):
        print("x.func() calls the method func on x w/ no parameters.")
x = X()

func(x)

x.func()
```

Output:

```
func(x) calls function func passing x as a parameter.
x.func() calls the method func on x w/ no parameters.
```

Comment: :D:D:D:D:D:D:D:D